# Why are copy constructors unnecessary for immutable objects?

Tags: language-agnostic, copy, immutability, copy-constructor

Why are copy constructors unnecessary for immutable objects? Please explain this for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What makes immutable objects to be published without safe publication techniques?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000617/what-makes-immutable-objects-to-be-published-without-safe-publication-techniques)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because the value cannot change, it's every bit as good to reference the same object in all cases, there's no need to have an "extra copy", so to speak.

Comment: +1 there's no point in having two instances of equal immutable objects - just use the same instance everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

This is a language dependent question especially with respect to lifetime.  For a moment lets forget about those.

Copy constructors are valuable in that they allow for you to take one object and create a completely independent copy of it.  This is valuable in that you can now modify the second object independent of the first.  Or a component can create a private copy to protect itself from other components changing the object out from under it.

Immutable objects are unchangeable.  There is no value in creating a copy of an object that won't change.

Now lets thing about lifetime again.  In languages like C++ copy constructors also allow you to work around memory / lifetime issues.  For example if I'm writing an API which takes a `SomeType*` and I want to keep it around longer than the lifetime of my method.  In C++ the most reliable way to do this is to create a copy of the object via a copy constructor.

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat language dependent:

However, many languages require a copy constructor.  If you don't provide one, the language will implicitly generate one.

With an immutable object, however, this is typically fine, since the default copy constructor (typically) does a shallow copy of all values.  With a mutable data type (ie: containing internal object references to other objects), shallow copying is typically a poor choice, since the copy is only copying the reference/pointer encapsulated within it.

Comment: Copying immutable objects is not optimal - it unnecessarily uses extra resources. This may or may not cause a problem depending on the situation, but copying immutable objects should be discouraged in general.

Answer (score 1):

it's so natural because value of immutable object can't be changed.